# Trying to fill in a form to login to a site via VBA but wont register the text I've entered

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

First time poster, long time user.

I'm trying to write a script in VBA to login to a site to then extract data at a later step.

I've hit a road block with trying to logon to the site, there is **three** classes that change once you manually fill in the username and password and **two** aria-invalid that turn from *true* to *false*. Unfortunately, this doesn't update if you try and fill in the forms via VBA.

This is the VBA code I currently have

```
Option Explicit
Sub LoginToSite()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://website.com.au"
Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
IE.Document.forms("form").elements("username").Value = "FredFlinstone"
IE.Document.forms("form").elements("password").Value = "Password000"
IE.Document.forms("form").elements("submit-button").Click
End Sub
```

This is the HTML before manual text is added into the forms:

```
`<form name="form" class="login-form ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" novalidate="" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="field-container">
                    <label for="username">
                        Username
                    </label>
                    <input name="username" class="ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" id="username" aria-invalid="true" required="" type="text" ng-keydown="vm.loginOnKeyEnter($event)" ng-class="vm.usernameEmptyClass" ng-model="vm.username">
                </div>
                <div class="field-container ">
                    <label for="password">
                        Password
                    </label>
                    <input name="password" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="password" aria-invalid="true" required="" type="password" ng-keydown="vm.loginOnKeyEnter($event)" ng-class="vm.passwordEmptyClass" ng-model="vm.password">`
```

These are the parts that change in the HTML if you manually add text.

Form div

```
<form name="form"
class="login-form ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required"
novalidate=""
autocomplete="off">
```

Username Div

```
<input name="username"
class="ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required"
id="username"
aria-invalid="false"
required=""
type="text"
ng-keydown="vm.loginOnKeyEnter($event)"
ng-class="vm.usernameEmptyClass"
ng-model="vm.username">
```

Password Div

```
<input name="password"
class="ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched"
id="password"
aria-invalid="false"
required=""
type="password"
ng-keydown="vm.loginOnKeyEnter($event)"
ng-class="vm.passwordEmptyClass"
ng-model="vm.password">
```

Very keen to learn what I need to change in order to trigger the site into realising there is text within the boxes to be able to login.

*I've still got my L plates on with VBA, so code will most definitely not be the most efficient code, but keen to hear of better methods to executing the above*

Thanks in advance Mr Swan

Comment: Try to .Focus on the element first then add the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the .Focus method to focus the TextBox first, then use the [SendKeys statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement) to enter the value.

Comment: I've given this a whirl, but I think I need to understand SendKey a little more to get this working

Answer (score 0):

Is everything on one page or is it split between two pages like the Gmail login?

1 page example: enter username, enter password, click login
2 page example: enter username (click next), enter password, click login

Comment: all on the one page

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work if it's single page but you'll have to fill out the SignIn Div information portion since this doesn't appear to be a valid URL.  Just follow the same format and note that everything is case sensitive.  TKs.

```
Sub LoginToSite()

Const cURL = "https://website.com.au"
Const cusername = "FredFlinstone"
Const cpassword = "Password000"

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim LoginForm As HTMLFormElement
Dim UsernameInputBox As HTMLInputElement
Dim PasswordInputBox As HTMLInputElement
Dim SigninButton As HTMLInputButtonElement

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate cURL

'Wait for initial page to load

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Set doc = IE.document

'Get the only form on the page

Set LoginForm = doc.forms(0)

'Get the Username textbox and populate it
'input name="username" id="username" size="18" value="" class="ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required" type="text"

Set UsernameInputBox = doc.getElementById("username")
UsernameInputBox.Value = cusername

'Get the Password textbox and populate it
'input name="password" id="password" size="18" class="ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" type="text"


Set PasswordInputBox = doc.getElementById("password")
PasswordInputBox.Value = cpassword

'Get the form input button and click it
'button class="XXXXX" name="XXXXX" id="XXXXX" value="XXXXX" type="text"

Set SigninButton = doc.getElementById("XXXXX")
SigninButton.Click

'Wait for the new page to load

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Jim, I gave this a whirl and it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you make sure to change the SigninButton information?  You would've had to have done that first.  I was able to fill out the rest because you provided the details but I didn't have any for that portion and the URL wasn't valid.  This is the part that needs changed though (everything in quotes):.....'Get the form input button and click it
'button class="XXXXX" name="XXXXX" id="XXXXX" value="XXXXX" type="text"
Set SigninButton = doc.getElementById("XXXXX")
SigninButton.Click...….If that doesn't work then I might know of one other approach.